# Script that grabs a Facebook like page's latest status?

Tags: facebook, token, status

I am trying to write a script that grabs the latest Facebook status. I get the latest status by calling https://graph.facebook.com/**LIKEPAGE**?fields=statuses.limit%281%29.fields%28message,updated_time%29&access_token=**TOKEN**

The problem is that the token expires. I read someting on Facebook about the problem. https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ 
Can a server access the page (graph.facebook) and fetch the JSON-response? Or do I have to make the user login everytime? That is an option, but I would like to avoid it if it is possible?

So, can I fetch the latest status via a PHP script without makeing the user login?

Answer (score 0):

You should dynamically generate the access token. For this you should first create a Facebook App, just create it and leave it empty. From this app you will get the Fb App ID and Fb App Secret. Then using this URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=FB_APP_ID&client_secret=FB_APP_SECRET

you will get the access token.

Comment: It worked! But I found anouther problem. 

I suppose that there is no way to grab a status without a user access token if I get the error-message: "A user access token is required to request this resource."

Comment: You want to get a user status? Or a page status?

Comment: You need to have this dynamically generated access token to get the page status.

Comment: By making the the user login? https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=FB_APP_ID&client_secret=FB_APP_SECRET gives you an access token, but not a user access token...

Comment: Use this link https://graph.facebook.com/pageid/feed?access_token=the-access-token-you-got-from-my-previus-link .

Comment: Thank you, now it works!

I have one last question. What way is the most effective way to parse the link? The output looks like this:"access_token=TOKEN123123123123".
This is my way to parse the token, but it's slow: 
$token = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=MYAPPID&client_secret=MYSECRETAPPID');
$token = str_replace("access_token=","",$token);

Comment: If you want to use php google "Getting jSON Data with PHP (curl method)"

Comment: Is there a way to fetch the latest event?
I tried this: https://graph.facebook.com/$FBid/feed?fields=events&limit=1&access_token=$myToken

But it does not work